# $_POST to SQL update problems problems

Tags: php, ios, mysql, post, phpmyadmin

I am trying to update a SQL table from a PHP script which gets its POST statements from a iPhone app I am trying to develop. The app runs fine, and the connections are there, however I have a feeling that the PHP script isn't picking up what I am sending from the app (since my database is not updated). I am using a standard app - PHP - database setup.

Could someone please check my PHP + post statement from the app side? I have   that is where it's breaking. If I run the PHP script my echo statements (below) are empty. I am posting all the code below.

PHP side

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
    $header = $_POST['header'];
//    $description = $_POST['description'];
//    $city = $_POST['city'];

  $sql = "UPDATE CityTable SET head=header WHERE id=1";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
} 
//    $para = $_POST['parameter'];
//    $parad = $_POST['parameterData'];
    var_dump($_POST);
    echo '<br>', '<br>';

    echo "Header, description and city:" , '<br>', '<br>';

    echo "Header : " .$header, '<br>';
    echo "Desc : " .$description, '<br>';
    echo "City : ".$city, '<br>','<br>';

//    echo "Para : " .$para, '<br>';
//    echo "Parad : ".$parad, '<br>';
$conn->close();

?>
```

My viewcontroller

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController{
    NSMutableData *mutableData;

#define URL            @"http://mydb.com/upload.php"  // change this URL
#define NO_CONNECTION  @"No Connection"
#define NO_VALUES      @"Please enter parameter values"

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

}

-(IBAction)sendDataUsingPost:(id)sender{

    [self sendDataToServer :@"POST"];

}

-(void) sendDataToServer : (NSString *) method{

    NSString *head  = header.text;
    NSString *desc = description.text;
    NSString *cty  = city.text;

    if(head.length > 0 && desc.length > 0 && cty.length > 0){

        serverResponse.text = @"Sending to server...";

        NSURL *url = nil;
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = nil;

        // Only Difference between POST and GET is only in the way they send parameters

        if([method isEqualToString:@"POST"]){

            NSString *parameter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"header=%@&description=%@&city=%@", head, desc, cty ];
            NSData *parameterData = [parameter dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
            url = [NSURL URLWithString: URL];
            request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
            [request setHTTPBody:parameterData];

        }

        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request addValue: @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

        NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

        if(connection)
        {

            mutableData = [NSMutableData new];

        }else{

            serverResponse.text = NO_CONNECTION;

        }

    }else{

        serverResponse.text = NO_VALUES;

    }

}

#pragma mark NSURLConnection delegates

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [mutableData setLength:0];
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [mutableData appendData:data];
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    serverResponse.text = NO_CONNECTION;
    return;
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSString *responseStringWithEncoded = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: mutableData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    //NSLog(@"Response from Server : %@", responseStringWithEncoded);
    NSAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[responseStringWithEncoded dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
    serverResponse.attributedText = attrStr;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

Comment: $sql = "UPDATE CityTable SET head=header WHERE id=1"; should be head='$header', right?

Comment: Your keyboard has a shift key. Please use it. I fixed your missing capitalisations for you.

Comment: You should use prepared statements.

Comment: this still doesnt explain why i am not seeing any values in the echo .$header statement? i am sending data from the app so it should show up there, but i think the php script is just not listening correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is missing variable `$header`.

Corrected query:

```
$sql = "UPDATE CityTable SET head='{$header}' WHERE id=1";
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include your variable `$header` in the query, that's why the value in `$header` is not been used to update the column *head* in your database.

Change this line:

```
$sql = "UPDATE CityTable SET head=header WHERE id=1";
```

to:

```
$sql = "UPDATE CityTable SET head= '".$header."' WHERE id= 1";
```

Comment: thank you but i am still not getting any data even to my PHP scrip. if i run the script the echo .$header value returned is empty, so thats a huge issue in this

Comment: @Saucepan, let me see the code for your form that does the POST.

Comment: its all above in the My ViewController code. Under the (void) sendtoServer statement. thank you!